# Alternative to window.location.reload()?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have  a button to remove components represented as cards in the html:

```html
<a class="btn btn-danger" (click)="removeComponent(dish.components[i].componentId)">⚠ Remove</a>
```

The structure of 'dish' is:

```ts
    name: { type: String, required: true},
    totalCost: { type: Number, required: true},
    components: [{
        componentId: { type: String, required: true},
        componentQuantity: { type: String, required: true},
    }],
```

I remove the component in components with removeComponent(id):

```ts
  removeComponent(componentId: string): void {
    this.dish!.components = this.dish!.components.filter(
      component => component.componentId !== componentId
    );
    this.dishService.updateDish(this.id!, this.dish!)
    .subscribe(() => window.location.reload());
  }
```

I don't think `window.location.reload()` is a nice solution to show the update in the html. But if I just use `.subscribe()` the change is not reflected for the user in the browser.

Is there alternative approach I should/could use? Perhaps for the entire removeComponent()-function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ChangeDetectorRef`:

```
constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef){
}


removeComponent(componentId: string): void {
    this.dish!.components = this.dish!.components.filter(
      component => component.componentId !== componentId
    );
    this.dishService.updateDish(this.id!, this.dish!)
    .subscribe(() => this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
);
  }
```

Comment: `this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` will suffice